# Stop awk search on a condition

Tags: r, bash, csv, awk

At the moment I have my R function generate an awk script to load, selectively, a subset of a csv into `fread`.

The resulting awk string looks something like this:

`tail -n +2 ../data/faults_main_only_dp_1_shopFlag.csv | parallel -k -q --block 500M --pipe awk -F , ' $5 > \"2013-01-01\" && $5 < \"2015-11-17\" && $2 ~ /^F59PHI$|^GP20ECO$|^GT42CU-ACE$/ && $20 ~ /^Disregard$|^EMD Work Item$|^Pending$|^Pre-Work Item$|^Road Failure$|^Unit Shopped$|^Watch$|^Work Item$|^NA$/ {print  $2 \",\" $88 \",\" $17 \",\" $5 \",\" $9 \",\" $22 \",\" $3 \",\" $15 \",\" $14 } '`

The thing is: as of recent, my csv is ordered by dates (`$5`), in descending order, so if the user enters a specific lower-bound date, and awk gets to that line, it make sense for it to stop. (I am not sure how that would work the parallelization I am doing above. Maybe there is a way to select only the part of the csv that is “above” the lower-bound of the date and then pass the resulting csv into the awk script.) Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Generate an awk program such as this which explitly exits on a condition (here if field 3 exceeds 4):

```
$2 > 3 & $2 < 10
$3 > 4 { exit}
```

Put the above in a file called `myprog.awk`, say, and assuming default separators run it with this (your awk may be called something else):

```
gawk -f myprog.awk mydata.dat
```

or put it on the command line but you will have to be careful regarding quoting depending on the shell you use:

```
$2 > 3 & $2 < 10; $3 > 4 { exit}
```

Comment: OK, just to clarify: I still need to use the command that I have shown above. I still need to select specific rows based on other filtering conditions (besides time) and then get specific columns. So, I am wondering how the command line that I presented above would be modified to include your command. Would I put the `; $3 > 4` bit after my command?

Comment: Thanks. For some reason it takes the same or more time to chew through 60 GB using the new command than the original one I had. (Note that I am parallelizing; don’t know if that changes anything.) That shouldn’t be happening, because my data are sorted in desc. order by time (`$5`).

Comment: This is the command: `time tail -n +2 head_cleaned_ALL_faults.csv | parallel -k -q --block 500M --pipe awk -F , ' $5 < "2015-11-15" && $2 ~ /^ABCD$/ {print  $1 "," $2 "," $3 "," $4 "," $5 "," $6 "," $7  }; $5 <= "2015-11-11" { exit} ' > temp_adam.csv`

Comment: Just tried it. `mawk` takes about the same time (ms difference).

Comment: Also, that doesn’t really explain why `… { exit }` is not taking less time.

Comment: exit is likely not taking less time because the first few parallel instances never encounter the exit condition and since the overrall time is not going to run any faster than the slowest instance there is no benefit.  If you remove the parallel processing it might help relative to not using it without the parallel processing.

Comment: OK, that makes sense. The command still makes sense to implement though, to reduce the memory pressure (for the cores that do encounter the exit condition), right?